# Toggle App Theme between Light and Dark Mode on Application Context Programmatically

Tags: android, android-studio, themes, android-theme

I am trying to add a theme change feature in my app but it's not effecting at the app context level and whenever I use application context it returns resources based on device theme not based on the theme I have set.

This is what I am using currently

```
    Resources resources = getResources();
    Configuration config = resources.getConfiguration();
    if (!isNightModeOn) {
        config.uiMode = Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO;
    } else {
        config.uiMode = Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES;
    }
    resources.updateConfiguration(config, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
    if (isNightModeOn) {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
    } else {
        AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
    }

    setTheme(R.style.Theme_MaterialTheme);
```

any help would be appreciated

thanks in advance